# VBA public variables

Tags: vba, excel, public

I am having trouble with the public i as intger portion of my code.
I am using i to keep the value of my current row so i can use this range across
my program. In my for loop it increments i so it will step through a column and search for v
however when i try using "i" in another set of code "i" no longer has a value.
I am not sure how global/public variables work in VBA or what is cause this error.

the problem occurs int Sub "yes" , and sub "no"
at the code

```
Cells(i,lcol).value=" ok "
```

and

```
Cells(i,lcol).value = " updated "
```

1st set of code is as follows, which gets my value for "i"

```
Public V As Integer
Public i As Integer

Private Sub Enter_Click()
Dim EmptyRow As Long

'Audit will only search Master Sheet
Worksheets("Master").Activate

'Find empty row value so we can use that for limit of search
With Sheets("Master")
     EmptyRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

'i needs to be set to minimum limit
'Begin loop of search
For i = 12 To EmptyRow + 1

    If Cells(i, 1).Value = V Then  'AssetNum.Value Then

        'Go to compare userform to display

        Compare.AssetDisplay.Value = AssetNum.Value
        Compare.LocationDisply.Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value
        Compare.Show

     End If
  Next i

    'If i gets to emptyrow num then go to non found asset userform
    Unload Me
    NonFoundAsset.Show

 End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Read in value from asset num to be comapre in loop
AssetNum.Value = V

End Sub
```

the second set of code im trying to call "i" using the public variable and it has no value

```
Private Sub No_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lcol As Long

'Make Master Sheet Active
 Worksheets("Master").Activate

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

'Finds next empty column

  With ws
        lcol = .Cells(11, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
  End With

'If the displayed location is not the same as the actual location "No" will be
'selected and the Change User Form will be displayed
'The value under the current audit column will be displayed as updated
 Cells(i, lcol).Value = " Updated "
 Unload Me
 AuditChange.Show

End Sub

Private Sub Yes_Click()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim lcol As Long

'Make Master Sheet Active
 Worksheets("Master").Activate

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

'Finds next empty column

  With ws
        lcol = .Cells(11, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
    End With

    'If the location displayed is correct "Yes" will be selected and
    'The value "ok" will be displayed in the current audit column

    Cells(i, lcol).Value = " Ok "
    Unload Me
    'Returns to Assetlookup to look for a new asset
    Assetlookup.Show
End Sub
```

I appreciate any help, Im new to VBA and don't understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where you declare it. You have to refer to that location.  So if i is in UserForm1 and you are trying to use it from another form, reference it as.

```
Cells(UserForm1.i,lcol).value=" ok "
```

If you put

```
Option explicit
```

at the top of the form you are trying to call it from it would tell you that i by itself is not defined in that scope of you code.

EDIT: For additional comments from OP. Asked if i can be public in a click event.

To my knowledge, you can't have public/global variables in an event.

You will have to use a variable local

```
'Public variables are declared outside (above) all subs and functions
'This will be accessible by all subs functions and events in in the forms or sheets module or wherever it is
Public i As Integer

'This will be accessible by all subs functions and events in in the CURRENT sheet or form. It is private but to the current item
Private i As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim j As count

    'Do whatever it is to get that value.
    j = 5

    'You can access i to use it in you click event code
    msgbox i * j

    'Or you can set it in the event
    i = j

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried with this line of code                                                                                  'Cells(Assetlookup.i, lcol).Value = " Ok "  '                                                                        But the variable I is in the button click of the userform. Is it possible to do the same with that?

Comment: I don't think so. You can't have a public variable in a click event.  You can pass the value of i out of the event to some public function.  Give me one moment and i will edit my answer.

Comment: since that is in the button_click command , can I still use ''Cells(Assetlookup.i, lcol).Value = " Ok " ' to call  the user form?

Comment: If you are asking if you can access/set the variables, Yes. From any event, sub, or function in that variables scope. If you have a form and you want to access form variables from the sheet click you will have to again refer to  it by UserForm.i

Answer (score 6):

I believe a public variabe in a UserForm is only available if the UserForm is running (loaded). To have a truely global variable, declare it in a normal module.

Probably the variable isn't available and VB can't find it in its scope. If *Tools, Options, Require variable declarations* is turned **OFF**, VB will create a new variable with that name in the current scope. Hence it looks as if it has "lost" its value.

Tip: don't call global variables something like `i, j, n` etc. These are typically used as local variables for loops and counters. Use a naming convention that makes clear the variable is global. I always prefix such a variable with `g` for 'global', e.g.:

```
Public giLoopCounter As Integer;
```